# Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded on Appium iOS real device

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I got "Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded" error on Appium when run iOS real device.
I tried every "Desired Capabilities" to increase timeout but not successful.

My Desired Capabilities:

```
{
  "deviceName": "iphone6s",
  "platformName": "IOS",
  "udid": "adbc8013455614ce0933a50aervgt7424077bc79",
  "bundleId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "wdaConnectionTimeout": 1000000,
  "newCommandTimeout": 15000,
  "wdaLaunchTimeout": 240000,
  "wdaStartupRetryInterval": 100000,
  "wdaLocalPort": 8102,
  "showXcodeLog": true,
  "usePrebuiltWDA": false
}
```

Log:

```
[iProxy@abb801b1:8102] Connection was refused to port 8102
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8102/status] with no body
[iProxy@abb801b1:8102] Connection was refused to port 8102
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8102/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8102/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded
```

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gWwp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Appium logs do not help here, I suggest checking **WebdriverAgent** diagnostic logs for better understanding why it may stuck:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-/Logs/Test`

There you should be able to find folders with .log files for each Appium session.

With current input, you can try [xcuitest-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver) capabilities like `appium:wdaEventloopIdleDelay` and `appium:waitForQuiescence`.

Also make sure you are using the latest stable version of Appium, delete WDA from your device before you try it again.